# will the protected question be deleted if the user gets deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts, protected-questions

I have one doubt. I know that if the user has delete his account all his voting will be reversed.

I also assume that question and their answers will also be deleted.

But what if there is a protected question post by the user.Will it also be deleted or is there a way to prevent those questions from being deleted ?

Comment: What if user who post the protected question tries to delete the question ?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that a protected question would not have an upvoted answer - which means it can't be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions of a deleted user wont be deleted if,

- It was not closed.
- It doesn't have negative scores.
- And it must not be a spam.

Answers of a deleted user wont be deleted if,

- The answer cotains positive scores.
- It would not be a spam.
- Correponding question would not be closed.In some cases closed questions will be deleted along with their answers.

Comment: *In some cases?* Which cases?

Comment: If both the question and answer wouldn't be helpful for future readers.

Comment: I assume it is automated one and not moderated by users. Can you please explain how would say that `both the question and answer wouldn't be helpful for future readers ` Was it based on votes that it received ?

Comment: It won't based on the votes received.In Ask Ubuntu, questions about Ubuntu versions which reached End Of Life are closed as offtopic.Answers to that question won't be helpful for the future readers because no one willing to install an unsupported version.In that case both the question and its corresponding answers would be deleted.